# Create Sales Order with large number of items

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am creating a new sales order through Restlet. When I add 5/6 items in the sales order, it is working without any error. But, when there is a large number of items ( above 15 items in my case), it is showing "Script Execution Usage Limit Exceeded" error.

I came to know this is because a large number of items in the order requires large memory and CPU usage. Thus, it throws the above error. I searched a lot about creating sales order with 10s of items, i came up to this answer: https://netsuiteprofessionals.com/blog/question/sales-order-creation-with-100-line-items/

Says:

> You can also import via csv in a single file – no separate header /
> line item file required.  Depending on the method and format of the
> data you are receiving to create the orders, you can develop an API or
> use an IPaaS of sorts to import via sFTP or other protocol.  If there
> is a set standard for the orders, as in always the same line items,
> you could potentially use a memorized transaction as well.  Either
> way, the good news is there’s options.

I checked the memorized transaction, but the time interval to execute between processes is 24 hour (minimum) which is of no use.
Now, I am stuck and have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Just to review the error you received:

"Script Execution Usage Limit Exceeded"

This error is generally relating to the governance units of the script you are executing. Checking the SuiteScript API, operations like "setCurrentSublistValue" or "setSublistValue" do not utilise any governance units, and thus leads me to believe something else (other than excessive lines as you mention) in your script is causing the issue.

Have you counted the number of API calls occurring in your script?

Please share more of the code to explore further.

Answer (score 1):

The number of lines you indicate should never be an issue. It sounds like what you are doing is a number of searches per item line.

Each item search uses 10 governance units (this varies depending on the type of record you are searching) Your RESTlet has a limit of 5000 units.

Posting the code of your script would be beneficial in helping you figure this out but the general approach is:

- collect whatever you are searching on and make an initial group search that contains enough information to group and serve as the basis for your other grouped searches e.g. `filters:[['itemid', 'is', 'X'], 'OR' ['itemid', 'is', 'Y']]`
- use a Map to collect information about each item and to build the criteria for your next grouped search.
- do this until you've collected or validated the REST payload and can then loop through the collected information to create your Sales Order.

An alternative that may allow a single query would be to use the  `N/query` module to create a single SQL query that brings all the information you need to validate your inputs and then proceed to create the order.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Restlet Custom? or are you calling the standard NetSuite create record/transaction to create your SO with multiple line items? Custom Restlet called via API should be sufficient for your needs, just how you designed it. However, if it’s a very complex SO creation, it is best to create a custom RESTLET that would call a task for Map/Reduce and pass the JSON data to params. That way when it hits governance limit, it will yield automatically for you

Comment: Indeed, using a map/reduce script is an alternative solution; however I would only use this solution as a final resort when using a RESTlet because the RESTlet response will not offer much information on the failure/success of Sales order creation. At best, you will receive a response that confirms if the M/R script was added to the scripting queue successfully.

Comment: True but at the same token, there’s nothing stopping someone from creating a custom error handling and rely on the logging once you’ve submitted the request via RESTlet / REST. At least thats how I would do it. Submit Request to RESTlet > run M/R > Custom Saved Search for Script Logs (M/R) > If you’re feeling extra, do a custom email notification otherwise stick to logs if you’re tracking realtime. As per OP, it’s quite vague without sample

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple .

Instead of creating Sales Orders directly , create a custom record to save the information that they send to your restlet .

Then have a workflow or Map/Reduce to convert this custom record to a sales order . Provide logs and alot of different information into it so you always know if anything goes wrong .

I would save the items as a JSON.stringified array with internal ids and quantities and whatever other info you need , so all you have to do after is literally JSON.parse and populate the sublist.

General tip : When working with Restlets to receive orders , always work with batches to avoid concurrency limits and script execution usage limits . Find a sweetspot for best performance and say i will only receive 25 SO's per request for example and you can have multiple concurrent requests without the RL crashing .

Refer to this for concurrency handling and info : https://nlcorp.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=127925362&c=NLCORP&h=8742ad8b887aa6881f85&_xt=.pdf